# Postgresql replace all occurrences of string+

Tags: regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

I have this string:

```
this is the abcd xxx
string I want to abcd yyy
replace in my text abcd zzz
```

Now I want to replace `abcd` and anything after it with blank.

I want this result:

```
this is the
string I want to 
replace in my text
```

I tried:

```
select regexp_replace(str, 'abcd.*','','gi')
```

But it just removed everything after the first match. Also other combos without luck.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the flag `n` (newline-sensitive matching) in `regexp_replace()`:

```
with my_table(str) as (
values(
'this is the abcd xxx
string I want to abcd yyy
replace in my text abcd zzz')
)

select regexp_replace(str, 'abcd.*','','gin')
from my_table

   regexp_replace    
-----------------
 this is the        +
 string I want to   +
 replace in my text 
(1 row)
```